# How to disable select/clipboard behavior in WP7 IE when using PhoneGap / Cordova

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

I am trying to create a simple Phonegap/Cordova app for WP7, using Cordova 1.7.0.

The VS 2012 project template displays a simple welcome message in index.html. When you touch the text on the screen the text turns to selected, and clipboard icon displayed. Also, if your page contains a picture, touching the pic turns it to be highlighted as selected.

This behavior makes the UI unusable, how can I prevent it?

What I've tried is:
a) all CSS -ms-user-selectable: none etc, 
and 
b) uselectable='on' attribute in elements.

None of these prevent the selectability of the UI elements.

(Note WP7 is Mango)

Any idea?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it with absolutely positioned pseudo element. For example, you have an element with text where you want to avoid selecting a text:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vitae orci condimentum magna sagittis congue eu at diam. <a href="#">Learn more</a></p>
```

CSS:

```
p {
    position:relative;
    z-index: 0;
}

p:before {
    content:''; 
    position:absolute; 
    top:0px; 
    left:0px; 
    right:0px; 
    bottom:0px; 
    z-index:1;
}

p a {
    position:relative; 
    z-index:2;
}
```

Z-index for link added to leave open the possibility to click on it, so be carefull if you have another clickable elements in this block. Solution is ugly as a lot of things for WP7, but it works.